# Managing layers/collections in blender 2.8

Tags: collections

I am trying to duplicate a layer in my collection. The layers its a background image and I would like to duplicate it in order to load a different image in the same position. Can not find the way of duplicate a layer.

Also would be nice to know how to move them in order to organise it within my collection. I can move them to a different collection, but I can not manage to organise them within my collection.